# Adding line numbers to VBA code (Microsoft Access 2016)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to be able to add line numbers to my VBA code so that I can use the erl function for error checking.  There is a tool-kit from www.fmsinc.com that might do the trick, but ideally, I'd like to be able code it myself so that I can also strip out the numbering if I need to.

Is there a way that I can read/modify the VBA code from within the application (it's an .accdb file)?  Assuming that there is, I should be able to prefix specific lines containing code with a number.